# Android viewpager width issue with fill_parent?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Hi all i have viewpager width  problem here. This is not taking the full screen width. Can you plz answer me?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/project_detail_layout"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
   android:id="@+id/pager"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   />
<com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
   android:id="@+id/indicator"
   android:padding="10dip"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
   />
```

And fragment code is this. I am here adding images dynamically here.
The images are loaded from chache or sdcards or downloaded in either case .

```
public static class ArrayListFragment extends Fragment {
    int mNum;

    static ArrayListFragment newInstance(int num) {
        ArrayListFragment f = new ArrayListFragment();

        // Supply num input as an argument.
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("num", num);
        f.setArguments(args);

        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mNum = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("num") : 1;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ImageView image = new ImageView(getActivity());
        //image.setImageBitmap(bitmap.get(mNum));
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(bitmap.get(mNum), image);
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        layout.addView(image);  
        return layout;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
       // setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
             //   android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Cheeses.sCheeseStrings));
    }
```

}

Can you plz tell me where i am Mistake ?

Comment: "fill_parent" is deprecated. it has been replaced with "match_parent" long ago.

Comment: I have updated the code but still the left and right side there is an space.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

change your layout width to match parent

```
android:layout_width="MATCH_PARENT"
```

Can you add this line to your **imageview** please

```
image.setScaleType(CENTER_CROP)
```

Comment: replacing fill_parent with match_parent doesnt change anything

Comment: can you add this line too image.setScaleType(CENTER_CROP)

Answer (score 1):

you can also try this..

```
   <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
```

Comment: Its not giving correct answer what i want .. Can you plz check the code again (i have updated it)